# What is the difference between app.all and app.use?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

What is the difference between `app.all()` and `app.use()`?

Comment: The documentation ([all](http://expressjs.com/api.html#app.all), [use](http://expressjs.com/api.html#app.use)) is pretty verbose about both. What exactly are you confused about?

Answer (score 7):

`app.all()` will be called when a particular URI is requested with any type of request method (e.g. GET, POST, PUT, or DELETE.)

`app.use()` on the other hand is more useful for any middleware you might have since it "mounts" onto a path prefix, and will be called anytime a URI under that route is requested. So for instance `app.use('admin/', isAuthorized)` could be a piece of middleware that will make sure any URI accessed under "admin/" (such as "admin/settings" or "admin/bing/bang") is being requested only by authorized users. If you don't provide a mount path, the default is to use the root URI "/".

You could do the same thing with `app.all()` by using a glob (e.g. `app.all('admin/*', isAuthorized)`), but `app.use()` does the extra step of stripping the mount URI from `req.path` which for some middleware is pretty useful.